# What are the WebClients' blocking equivalents of RestTemplate's CRUD operations?

Tags: java, spring

I have a question relating to the deprecation of RestTemplate. I have read that as an alternative, it is possible to use WebClient in a blocking fashion but I cannot find on the Internet the four major parts of the REST to perform CRUD.

I've been looking for months now but I cannot find the information I need.

I am using Spring Boot with Java 11.

In the following code, what are the WebClient equivalents?

I thank the community in advance.

```
@Service

public class UserService implements IUserService {

    

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public User[] findAll()

    {

        
        
        ResponseEntity<User[]> response =
                  restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8082/api/users/",
                  User[].class);
        User[] users = response.getBody();
        
        return users;
        
        
        
        
    }

    public User create(@RequestParam User s) {

        User createdUser = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8082/api/users", s, User.class);

        return createdUser;

    }

    public User findById(long id) {

        User foundUser = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/api/users/" + id, User.class);

        return foundUser;

    }

    public void update(User s) {


        
        restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8082/api/users", s, User.class);

        
        
        
    }

    public void delete(long id) {

        restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:8082/api/users/" + id, User.class);
    }

}

/* Code created by Ramesh Fadatare

https://www.javaguides.net/2022/09/spring-boot-rest-api-crud-example-with-mysql-database.html


*/

package com.code;

import com.code.springbootrestfulservices.entity.User;
import com.code.springbootrestfulservices.services.UserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    // build create User REST API
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        User savedUser = userService.createUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // build get user by id REST API
    // http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
        User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Build Get All Users REST API
    // http://localhost:8080/api/users
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers(){
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Build Update User REST API
    @PutMapping("{id}")
    // http://localhost:8080/api/users/1
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId,
                                           @RequestBody User user){
        user.setId(userId);
        User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Build Delete User REST API
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId){
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User successfully deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I am not using Mono or Flux since this is not an asynchronous program.

Comment: Please have a look:https://ordina-jworks.github.io/rest/2020/10/12/RestTemplate-vs-WebClient.html#:~:text=RestTemplate%20provides%20a%20synchronous%20way,boot%2Dstarter%2Dweb%20dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/webclient-get-post-example/